# Pydantic schemas throws error although in payload needed properties exists

Tags: python, flask, backend, pydantic

In my flask + react project I use pydantic for validation of front-end payload.
I have properties of payload coded as below:

```
class PersonsSchema(BaseModel):
    id = str
    name: Optional[str]
    lastName: Optional[str]


class TagSchema(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
    id: str


class UpdatedActionSchema(BaseModel):
    id: str
    description: str
    action: str
    category: str
    tag: TagSchema
    persons: Optional[List[PersonsSchema]] = None
```

Can You please let me know why when I check the payload in my 'PUT' method I'm getting an error which indicates that I don't have such properties, this is the error:
[image]

My backend code looks like this:

```
@blp.route('/action/<string:actionId>', methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
def get_action(actionId):
    id = actionId

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        data = request.json
        key_to_lookup = 'id'
        for person in data['persons']:
            if key_to_lookup not in person:
                person['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        print(f"data:{data}")
        actions_schema = UpdatedActionSchema()
        try:
            actions_schema.parse_obj(data)
        except ValueError as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400
```

When I print in the terminal my payload it shows me this code, seems all properties are there:

```
data:
    {
        'action': 'asd',
        'category': 'asd',
        'description': 'asd',
        'id': '64c728b8-ba61-4038-890e-caadb79a5548',
        'persons': 
            [
            {
                'id': 'e01c8916-0d82-4155-a1b8-a55ded7c1674',
                'lastName': 'zzz',
                'name': 'aaa'
                },
            {
                'name': '',
                'lastName': '',
                'id': '84155298-dd72-490c-bc9a-4f72c8d7cd2f'
            }
    ],
    'tag': 
        {
            'action_id': '64c728b8-ba61-4038-890e-caadb79a5548',
            'id': '56d6c9ca-695f-45bb-aa00-319aa788b985',
            'name': 'asd'
        }
}
```

I have spent some time on it but cannot figure out.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pydantic there is not necessary to create an object then use method parse_obj like normal python classes, you can directly use `UpdatedActionSchema.parse_obj(data)`.

As @python_user mentions there is also an error in the schema. id: str, If you need something to be default value only then use an `=` in the Model class.